# Compile .mlmodel to .mlmodelc for Xamarin.iOS?

Tags: ios, xamarin, machine-learning, xamarin.ios, coreml

I want to use CoreML for my Xamarin.iOS app but how can I use models? All samples in developer.xamarin is use .mlmodelc but I downloaded .mlmodel. How can I convert to .mlmodelc?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use Xcode to compile your model:

```
xcrun coremlcompiler compile MyModel.mlmodel MyModel.mlmodelc
```

This outputs an .mlmodelc that you can add to your project.

Or you can do it dynamically inside your app by using `MLModel.compileModel(at:)`.

Comment: That's not quite right, because it will result in model package nested inside the same package (ex. if we run this code in home directory, output model will be in ~/MyModel.mlmodelc/MyModel.mlmodelc). So you need to specify only output folder without filename as the second parameter, like this for example: `xcrun coremlcompiler compile MyModel.mlmodel .`

Answer (score 2):

You can also use this command in Mac terminal:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/coremlc compile coreml.mlmodel
```

Comment: Remember to put output path ("coremlc: Error: compile command missing destination path")

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the below steps:

Step 1: Open Terminal and check the present directory using 'pwd' command.

Step 2: Go to your directory/folder from present directory where .mlmodel file is located using cd command, example:  'cd Desktop/mlfolder'.

Step 3: Enter below command

```
   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/coremlc compile model_name.mlmodel model_name.mlmodelc
```

Note: here model_name.mlmodel is the name of the mlmodel(you can name your model name here) and model_name.mlmodelc is the converted modelc name(name need not be same).